# Which ending to Deus Ex: HR is considered the canonical one?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

Having just finished Deus Ex: Human Revolution without having played the original Deus Ex, I'm wondering if any of the four available endings should be considered canonical with respect to the original game, or maybe they all fit somehow?

I'm guessing this should be obvious to someone who has played the original, but as I said it's still on my list :)

Comment: Ah, I had been meaning to ask this. Honestly, I tend towards thinking the "Let's just blow everyone up" ending was the canonical one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It really doesn't matter which one you pick, for Deus Ex. It might matter if they bring out another game that's a prequel to Deus Ex.

Really the only 3 things that tie into Deus Ex, you as the player had no control over:

> 1. Freeing Tracer Tong from prison/whatever he was trapped in. 2. Not killing Megan Reed and 3. Bob Page's little easter egg ending.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that there is no canonical ending.

The original Deus Ex offered three endings which were seemingly exclusive - however, if you have played Invisible War then all the tree endings were taken into account in the game - there were multiple references of J.C.Denton destroying the global communications hub, as well as he merged with Helios to become a "creature" and finally the Illuminati took control through the WTO and The Order.

If ever there is a fourth game in the Deus Ex series, that might find a way to accomodate all the four endings.